# How does the C++ compiler (or Linker?) knows how to handle cpp and header class files?

Tags: c++, class, compilation, linker, header-files

For example, I have a class Foo. I create `Foo.h`, `Foo.cpp` and then I include `Foo.h` in the `main.cpp` file. When I compile the code, how does the machine know to associate the class header file and the class cpp file? Is it done by the filenames?
I'm really interested in understanding this process of compilation and linking.

Comment: The two files are not associated. There's no need. And neither the compiler nor the linker get included files as files, because before that, the preprocessor step throws everything together.

Comment: This site is here to answer specific question on problems with code. You are looking  for a C tutorial.

Comment: It doesn't associate file names at all, it only looks for symbol names. Your `main.o` will have references to symbols _declared_ in `Foo.h`, those symbols are _defined_ in `Foo.cpp` so will be found in `Foo.o` at link time.

Comment: some good reading: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.2/cpp_2.html

Comment: Once the preprocessor has included the header file and finished, then the compiler "proper" doesn't know about it at all. All the compiler knows about are [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)). [This reference about the different phases of translation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases) might also be useful to read.

Comment: I'm not convinced that the question is _too broad_, at least we should have an appropriate duplicate!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When i compile the code how does the machine know to associate the class header file and the class cpp file? is it doing it by the files name?

No, there's no such kind of automatic association done by the compiler.

If you have a header file containing all the declarations of functions and classes, it must be `#included` from any translation unit (`.cpp` file), that makes use of it.
That step (of declaration contracts) is done by the c-preprocessor where every occurrence of `#include "MyDeclarations.hpp"` replaces that with the complete file content of `MyDeclarations.hpp` in the translation unit.

---

A simple example:

**Foo.hpp**

```
 class Foo {
 public:
      Foo(); // Constructor declaration
 };
```

**Foo.cpp**

```
 #include "Foo.hpp" // <<<< Include declarations

 Foo::Foo() {} // Constructor definition
```

**main.cpp**

```
 #include "Foo.hpp" // <<<< Include declarations

 int main() {
      Foo foo; // <<<<< Use declarations
 }
```

---

To finally instruct your linker to stich all of these files together you have to refer to the artifacts produced from the *translation units*. Depending on the toolchain a bit, but for e.g. GCC you may use some compiler command line like

```
 $ g++ main.cpp Foo.cpp -o myProg
```